# VBA - Get Preset Shadow.Type of a chart after other ShadowFormat properties have been modified

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to determine what the `.Format.Shadow.Type` of an object is (ChartArea in this example). The issue is that once you modify another property of the ShadowFormat, the `.Type` returns -2, which is a [msoShadowType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Office-Shared-VBA/articles/msoshadowtype-enumeration-office) meaning msoShadowMixed.

One aspect of this project is to copy chart elements from one chart (Chart1), and apply them to a different chart (Chart2)

```
With Chart1.ChartArea.Format.shadow
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value = .Visible
    Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value = .Style
    Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).Value = .Type
    Sheet1.Cells(4, 2).Value = .ForeColor.RGB
    Sheet1.Cells(5, 2).Value = .Transparency
    Sheet1.Cells(6, 2).Value = .Size
    Sheet1.Cells(7, 2).Value = .Blur
    Sheet1.Cells(8, 2).Value = .OffsetX
    Sheet1.Cells(9, 2).Value = .OffsetY
End With
```

You will see in the below example what happens when I apply these settings back to another chart. My Chart1 in the above example had an original type `Chart1.ChartArea.Format.Shadow.Type = 21`, but if I were modify one property such as the size `Chart1.ChartArea.Format.Shadow.Size = 101`, the original now returns `.Type = -2`.

This is an issue because if you applied each of the values that we captured above, to another chart, the two shadows would not be equal. This is because Chart1 had a base preset that was then changed. I believe the ShadowFormat settings are applied after a `.Type` is selected.

Here the settings of Chart1 are applied to Chart2. It is important to note that Chart2 has no `.Type` selected. It had no shadow prior to the shadow being applied in the below code.

```
With Chart2.ChartArea.Format.shadow
    .Visible = Sheet1.Cells(1, 2).Value
    .Style = Sheet1.Cells(2, 2).Value
    .Type = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2).Value
    .ForeColor.RGB = Sheet1.Cells(4, 2).Value
    .Transparency = Sheet1.Cells(5, 2).Value
    .Size = Sheet1.Cells(6, 2).Value
    .Blur = Sheet1.Cells(7, 2).Value
    .OffsetX = Sheet1.Cells(8, 2).Value 
    .OffsetY = Sheet1.Cells(9, 2).Value
End With
```

This is what both charts look like before anything is changed. Chart1 has a very defined shadow for example purposes. Note that I first applied a preset of `.Type = 21` to Chart1 and then modified the other properties as such: `.Transparency = 0, .Size = 101, .Blur = 0, .OffsetX = 4,.OffsetY = 4`

[image]

The result of the applying the second batch of code are shown below:
[image]

You can see that the shadows are not equal. If I were to replace the value in `Sheet1.Cells(3,2).Value = 21` instead of the -2 it pulled from Chart1, we get two charts that look like this:

[image]

Finally, I'm asking if there is away around this. I want to know if there was an original preset, or how I can take the preset into account when copying the ShadowFormat of one object to another.

Hopefully I gave enough information. Thank you